# Why does my NetSuite Create Operation not return any of the custom fields?

Tags: integration, netsuite, middleware, boomi

I have full access to the fields on NetSuite as an Administrator. There are 4 custom fields on the 'classification' record type that are not pulling into the XML Profile in Boomi. It appears that this behavior only happens with the 'classification' record type, as I also query the 'subsidiary' record type in another process, and it returns the custom fields fine, some of which are the same. I have attached a picture here for reference.
[Classifcation Create Operation Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d85B.png)